# Relationship with RKObjectMapping and RKEntityMapping by primary key

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

My response JSON should be like below

```
"status":

        [{  
            "id":1,
            "post_id":1,
            "post_status":"accepted"        
        },          
        { 
            "id":2,
            "post_id":2,
            "post_status":"rejected"        
        }]
}
```

I done an `RKObjectMapping`to map this response. In that response "post_id" was primary key of an entity named "Post" and it's attribute named is "postID". Now I would like to map the `NSManagedObject` of "Post" to an instance variable on "Status" class. So my "Status" class will be like as below :

`@interface OrdersDetail : NSObject <RestKitObjectProtocol>`

`@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *statusId;`

`@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *postID;`

`@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *postStatus;`

`@property (strong, nonatomic) Post *post;`

`@end`

So it seem to be an relationship between `RKObjectMapping` and `RKEntityMapping` and that need to be implemented by a primary key. Is it possible make it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

No, you generally can't mix object and entity mappings (though some cases with nesting will work ok).

The JSON you show doesn't include all of the items you're talking about wanting to connect. You should consider keeping the mappings separate and then, in the success completion block, use the mapping response and a fetch request to collect the required information and form the link you want.